# Laravel how to get count follower by user id?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have laravel jquery below

```
public function getFollower(Request $request){

      $userId = $request->get('user_id');

      $artists =  DB::table('artists')
      ->select('artists.id', 'artists.title as name ','artists.src as poster','followers.user_id',DB::raw('COUNT(followers.user_id) as followers'))
      ->leftjoin('followers', 'artists.id','=', 'followers.artist_id') 
      ->where('artists.status',0)
      ->groupBy('followers.artist_id')
      ->orderBy('followers.id', 'desc')
      ->get();

    return Response()->json(['data' => $artists], 200);
}
```

I want to get **Result** as below

```
 data: [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name ": "Artist 3",
      "poster": "",
      "user_id": 1,
      "followers": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name ": "Hello Artist 2",
      "poster": "",
      "user_id": 1,
      "followers": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name ": "Thai",
      "poster": "",
      "user_id": 3,
      "followers": 10
    }
  ]
```

If I use ->where('followers.user_id',$userId) by result will get `followers: 1` only

Anyone can help me how can I get result as above that I can use `->where('followers.user_id',$userId)`

Thanks!

Comment: when I logged In I want to get Artist which I followed them and each artist show count total follower

Comment: If I use this func ->where('followers.user_id',1)  I could not get follower result count only 1 why ?

Comment: why not use relationship instead of hardcoding this ?

Comment: Sorry, What you mean relationship instead of hardcoding  ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

This is a many to many relationship .. what you will do is

**MODEL ARTIST**

```
protected $appends = ['followers_count'];

public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','follower','artist_id','user_id');
}

public function getFollowersCountAttribute()
{
    return count($this->followers);
}
```

**MODEL USER**

```
protected $appends = ['followed_count'];
public function artists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artist','follower','user_id','artist_id');
}

public function getFollowedCountAttribute()
{
    return count($this->artists);
}
```

in your **CONTROLLER**

```
public function getArtists(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->get('user_id');
    // get the user using the user_id
    $follower = User::with('artists')->find($user_id);
    return response()->json(['data' => $follower ], 200);
 }
```

> this will return you an array of data like

```
{
    id: 1,
    name:'You',
    followed_count: 2,
    artists: [
        {
            id:1,
            name: 'Demonyowh',
            follower_count: 9999,  
        },
        {
            id:5,
            name: 'Brian',
            follower_count: 9999,  
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thank for help! can you help change how can I get artist by user_id ?

Comment: In my database I followed 3 artisst but I get only 1 artist result

Comment: may i see the structure of your database ?

Comment: I have table: 1.users  2.Artists  3.Follower

Comment: I hope you can help

Comment: Hi, I do thanks for your help. but I still did not get result as my data result above. total of followers is count from table follower where user is followed artists thanks you

Comment: ahhhh ok i see .. so the followers is not the count of an artist's followers but the count of the artist the user followed right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Table structure

```
 1. users
  - id 
  - name

2. follower
  - id
  -user_id
  -artist_id

3. artists
  -id
  -name
  -src
```

Thank you for help

Comment: follower related to artists and related to users.